# Convergence of a sequence(linear, superlinear,quadratic)

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I need to determine if the following sequence converges linearly, super linearly, or quadratically.

$$x_n=2^{a_n}$$ with $a_0=a_1 =1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$ for $n \ge 2$

I know that we need to use the formula $\lim_{k \rightarrow \inf} \frac{|x_{k+1}-L|}{|x_{k}-L|}=$ linear if 1, quadratic if 2, superlinear if 0.

Having trouble with applying the conditions of the sequence , can't construct the limit.

I got $\lim_{n \rightarrow int}2^{-a_{n+1}}$

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence diverges. $(a_n)_{n\in{\Bbb N}}$ grows exponentially (is the Fibonacci sequence) and $(x_n)_{n\in{\Bbb N}}$ grows even faster.